# Django Circular References

Tags: python, django

I have run into quite a few scenarios where I need to adjust my models.py files to avoid circular dependencies.

Here is the latest example.  I have registration/models.py, which looks like this (I've removed the vast majority of the code for simplicity's sake):

```
from user_profile.models import UserProfile

class UserManager(BaseUserManager):

@transaction.atomic()  # We definitely do not want to create a User record without a UserProfile
def _create_user(self, email, **kwargs):

    user_profile = UserProfile.objects.create_user_profile(first_name, last_name)

    email = self.normalize_email(email)
    user = self.model(email=email,
                      **kwargs
                      )

    user.set_password(password)
    user.save()

    return user


class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin, TimeStampedModel):
     email = models.EmailField('email address',
                          max_length=user_model_settings.get('EMAIL_MAX_LENGTH'),
                          unique=True,
                          blank=False
                          )

    user_profile = models.OneToOneField(UserProfile,
                                    null=False,
                                    )
```

I learned later that the UserProfile model (defined in user_profile.models.py) should point to the User, not the way it is currently.

(Initially, I had a profile_picture column in the User model that linked to the Picture model. I noticed that User records started disappearing whenever I deleted Picture records. This is due to cascading deletes. I reversed the foreign key so that the Picture points to the User and wanted to do the same thing with the UserProfile.)

Unfortunately, if the user_profile/models.py imports registration/models.py, then registration/models.py can no longer import user_profle/models.py and thus can no longer create the UserProfile record inside its manager using the UserProfile manager.

I get that these two models are tightly coupled... should they just be inside the same app? How do I prevent this sort of issue. I have seen 3rd party frameworks split their managers into separate files, but I would still have the same issue if I did this. How do I get around this?

I guess I just need a little guidance here. I have very little experience with large applications and haven't had to manage dependencies in a sophisticated way before.

Thank you for the help,
Nick

EDIT: I should note that I know I can resolve all of these issues by just importing user_profile.models within the _create_user function, but as I understand, this is bad practice.

Comment: Are you overriding django User model but not extending it?

Comment: I should have mentioned that. I am overriding the model. I found I got enormous performance gains by putting all the commonly used fields in the overridden User model instead of an extended model via OneToOne foreign key. Then settings and less commonly used fields are in the UserProfile.

Comment: So I guess I am both overriding and extending the User model. Is this my issue? Do I not need to extend the User model at all? The performance gains I got before were from when I initially overrode the User model. Maybe I should have just entirely gotten rid of the user_profile then. Are there disadvantages to storing extra fields in a model that will not be used often? Does a SELECT * query take longer if there are more columns (I'd think it would)? Or is this effect negligible?

Comment: Interesting, because normally I'd extend the **User Model** by creating a **CustomUser** model, pointing back to **User Model** and change the `AUTH_USER_MODEL`. Or, create a complete new **CustomUser** model inheriting `AbstractBaseUser`, with all the manager stuff.

Comment: Currently you are overriding the existing **User** model, adding new fields but also extending it with a one-to-one **UserProfile** model, which in my humble opinion, doesn't sound right and it is surely tightly coupled which makes it unlikely future proof. If I were you, I may rewrite the whole thing with just one **CustomUser** model with all the fields you need, remember you also need to take care of **superuser** etc.

Comment: You really extend the `User` model and override it, Do you really get performance improvement? And as I know, Django don't use the `SELECT *` query, it use something like `SELECT id, .... user_name`

Comment: Anzel, that's the same conclusion I was drawing as I wrote out those comments. That's what I'll do then. It shouldn't be too difficult. Thank you for the advice.

Comment: At a glance, it sounds like you just need to not import other models.py files and define refs using `"app.model"` as a string.

Comment: @Nick, yes you're right I typed really slowly... ;) good luck